# append inner table as per outer table id through jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I  am binding outer table and inner table with json. As per outer table id inner table is binded. As described in below format.

```
 <div id="dvCustomers"><table id='111' class="outer"><tr><td>

<div id ="dvCustomers1"><table id='222' class='inner'><tr><td>aaaa<td></tr></table></div>

<div id ="dvCustomers1"><table id='223' class='inner'><tr><td>bbbb<td></tr></table></div>

<div id ="dvCustomers1"><table id='224' class='inner'><tr><td>ccc<td></tr></table></div>

</td></tr><table>

<table id='112' class="outer"><tr><td>

<div id ="dvCustomers1"><table id='226' class='inner'><tr><td>dddd<td></tr></table></div>

</td></tr><table>

<table id='113' class="outer"><tr><td>

<div id ="dvCustomers1"><table id='227' class='inner'><tr><td>aaaa<td></tr></table></div>

<div id ="dvCustomers1"><table id='228' class='inner'><tr><td>bbbb<td></tr></table></div>

<div id ="dvCustomers1"><table id='229' class='inner'><tr><td>ccc<td></tr></table></div>

<div id ="dvCustomers1"><table id='230' class='inner'><tr><td>bbbb<td></tr></table></div>

<<div id ="dvCustomers1">table id='231' class='inner'><tr><td>ccc<td></tr></table></div>

</td></tr><table></div>
```

Currently I am not getting the inner table position as per outer table. Rateher I am getting data as per outer table, All my inner table get attach to first table, instead of following it's respective table.

I am using this code

```
var table = $("dvCustomers1 table").eq(0).clone(true); 
$(".sno", table).html(inncomm.find("SNo").text());
$(".name", table).html(inncomm.find("Name").text());
$(".dates", table).html(inncomm.find("Date").text());
$("#dvCustomers1").append(table).append("<br />");
```

How can I set position of  new table(inner table)created  dynamically , to there respective Outertable. For example if I want to insert innertable id=225, to divcustomer1 of outertable='111'.. How to do

Comment: Hi I think you would like to enter id dynamically to all your inner table based on your outer table ?

Comment: No , I am getting the inner table id as per behavior no problem with that . I am having  issue related filling innertable correctly. Right now I am filling the innertable with data as per outertable id , but it's not doing right. The top most innertable data are added to (other innertable after 10th record,having different outertable id) . As well as innertable data are repeted twice . Please look this one reposted with updated code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268628/table-append-issue-in-jquery