# table append issue in jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I was facing this problem from long time posted twice in this forum but didn't get any help.Please look out the code here. IF want more I will post.

My first post with demo table is here 
 [append inner table as per outer table id through jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258535/append-inner-table-as-per-outer-table-id-through-jquery).

on second post I put my code :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251157/filling-nested-listview-on-proper-place-with-json

As lot of trial I solved that issue by this

```
var table = $("dvCustomers1 table").eq(0).clone(true); 
$(".sno", table).html(inncomm.find("SNo").text());
$(".name", table).html(inncomm.find("Name").text());
$(".dates", table).html(inncomm.find("Date").text());
   $("#MainBox"+id).find("#dvCustomers1").append(table).append("<br />");
```

but now I am stuck with another problem that my inner table after 10th  row repets's it's data twice and all also add first innertable data to all appended table. Seriouslly not getting this one.Pleas give some suggestions